# What to do about original content that got copied and translated into another language on multiple domains?

Tags: seo, translation, disavow-links, infringement

A couple of weeks ago I published a long and well-researched article on my blog, which got quiet a lot of attention on the web.

After doing a backlink-analysis of my domain a couple of days ago, it turns out that this article was translated 1:1 into Russian and published on multiple, shady domains. All the original images were copied as well.
I noticed a slight drop of my domain authority rank probably due to these bad backlinks.

I already used Google's disavow-tool to exclude these URLs.

However, is there anything else I can do?

Do I have to report a copyright infringement with Google?

Comment: File a DMCA complaint here: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-dashboard

Comment: "due to these bad backlinks." - presumably these Russian sites are "trying" to attribute the original author (you)?

Answer (score 1):

Disavowing was the first suggestion I had.

I would file a complaint with Google. Once the claim is processes they will de-index the page or hit them with a manual action that will knock them from the SERP (though neither are guaranteed).

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-notice?pli=1&

Comment: Filing a DMCA complaint is the only real course of action that will have any real effect. Then you can disavow the links. It is like a wave hello only a bit lazy on the finger raising. ;-)